# Expand a matrix with filler values

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix like

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I would like to expand it, to, say, 5x5, and fill the new cells with some given value (say 0), so that the new matrix looks like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    4    7    0    0
[2,]    2    5    8    0    0
[3,]    3    6    9    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

How could I do this with basic R functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a `matrix` of 0s and assign

```
m2 <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
m2[seq_len(nrow(m1)), seq_len(ncol(m1))] <- m1
```

---

Or another option is `bdiag`

```
library(Matrix)
as.matrix(bdiag(m1, diag(2) * 0))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    4    7    0    0
#[2,]    2    5    8    0    0
#[3,]    3    6    9    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
```